# Mudar cor da coluna(chart) com valores acima do limite

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

Estou fazendo um relatório para winforms utilizando o REPORT viewer, nesse relatório acrescentei um gráfico de colunas. O que preciso fazer é que antes de carregar o relatório o usuário possa escolher qual o valor bom para ele, e todas as colunas que estiveram acima desse valor mudem sua cor para vermelho.Alguém tem idéia de como fazer isso, bom não tem código apenas alimento o relatório com um data set e utilizo as próprias propriedades do chart para criar a serie.

Comment: a estrutura do DataSet já está enviando a informação do valor a ser comparado correto?

Comment: Sim só preciso comparar seja por expression ou não.

Answer (score 1):

Eu consegui fazer da seguinte forma...

```
Series D = new Series("", listaLotes.Count);
            D.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
            for (int i = 0; i < listaLotes.Count; i++)
            {
                D.Points.AddXY(i + 1, listaLotes[i].Media);
                if (D.Points[i].YValues[0] > 7.0)
                {
                    D.Points[i].Color = Color.Red;
                }
            }
```